# How to get Google Sheet to trigger a dialog box if/when a cell value is larger than another?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-finance

I want to make a script to get the google sheet populates a dialog box alert and if possible, sends an email on the condition that a particular cell value (say A1 is larger than A2) and since the A1 and A2 value depend on the query returns from google finance, their cell value should update automatically, I am wondering if the Onedit functionis the right route, or are there any ways to do it properly?

I shall be grateful if anyone could provide a simple example of how should it be done.

Thank you in advance, appreciate your time.

Comment: onEdit won’t work for changes in google finance functions. You will probably have to use a time based trigger.

Comment: Just as a point of information.  You may come to the conclusion that the google finance functions update every two minutes.  However, I worked on a project recently in which I found that you will get occasional glitches in that behavior.  I've seen inconsistencies ranging all the from 80 seconds to 6 minutes between trading times.